# Jersey REST:How to write a jersey method including verifying HTTP Authorization

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am writing a Restful webservice method,which require authorization first...
such as a findItems method..which need username and password in Http Authorization 
the sample code:

```
@GET
@Produce(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String findItems(){

...
}
```

how to verify the http authorization before the method excutes...

Comment: I'm afraid not, there are differences between JAX-RS and JAX-RS...My question is about JAX-RS.

Comment: Is there a simple way that just to get Http Authorization(basic or digest) ?

Comment: I can't understand your last question, can you elaborate?

Comment: HTTP 1.1 contains AUTHORIZATION ,right?..so can i access the authorization info in the header of this url,and verify the info?

Comment: The way I suggested in my answer is the standard way of implementing security on RESTful web services in Java EE 6. Obviously you can implement it in other ways, but I can't help on that

Answer (score 0):

I use a user-type and role-type control with a basic JAAS authentication. After authentication, the client makes http GET requests to the REST web service. In my Facade get method, I inject the `@Context SecurityContext` as input parameter, and use if for user / role identification in order to provide the correct answer to the GET request, depending on the user's role.

See here for an example of what I mean:
[Using JaaS with Jersey on Grizzly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682061/using-jaas-with-jersey-on-grizzly/1684342#1684342)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Filters` so you can check the authorization

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902427/user-authentication-on-a-jersey-rest-service

Comment: Is there a simple way that just to get Http Authorization(basic or digest) ?