# Jersey client form-based authentication

Tags: jersey

Is it possible to do form-based authentication using Jersey Client?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676588/how-can-you-authenticate-using-the-jersey-client-against-a-jaas-enabled-web-serv)

Comment: I used this example. But I'm getitting an error: Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://localhost:8080/login/j_security_check returned a response status of 408 Request Timeout, but also what I noticed if I put wrong password for user it returns login page.

Comment: saw the example pointed by the link but how to implement this with Jersey 2.x?