# How to get Session id after validating a user in Restful service?

Tags: java, rest, session

I am working on Restful web Service.I tried to create session id(from your example).Your example is working fine.I have just made few changes(1.**Added Parameter** to the method,created the session id **after validating the user** and my method type is **POST**)

Its throwing error for me(that method returning me a null value)

This is how my method will look like

```
 public String SessionId(
     @Context HttpServletRequest req,
     @PathParam("username") String username,
     @PathParam("passwd") String passwd)
```

I gave existing username and password.but still its throwing an error.

please tell me,where i have done wrong.

Thanks in Advance,
Sudha.

Comment: Please use code tags. Whose example? What is the body of the method? Nobody will be able to help you without more information.

Comment: This is the example i refered [rest example program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909185/jersey-security-and-session-management).I got session id, i tried in new package and the error is resolved. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @SudhaVelan Please don't add contextless tag-links into post-bodies. These don't add any value beyond the tags in the tag-section.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885938/1561948

```
   @Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {
        @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String validateuser(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {

        HttpSession session= req.getSession(true);
        Object foo = session.getAttribute("uid");
        if (foo!=null) {
            System.out.println(foo.toString());
        } else {
            foo = "bar";
            session.setAttribute("uid", "bar");
        }
        return foo.toString();

    }
}
```