# Where to store Session Attributes with angular js

Tags: angularjs, sessionstorage, angular-local-storage

I am new to Angular JS, have experience on building spring web applications.

My requirement is to store the some session preferences (Not part of the user Model/entity) into session. I need to use them through out the application.

I couldn't find the right way to do it. I found some options, need suggestion on which one to use it.

ngStorage - can access Local/session storage and store attributes in it.

LocalStorageService - another githubproject, i can use it to store in session storage/ local storage.

Based on the articles i found, localstorage keeps the data even after logout, so have to make sure i clean all of them after logout.

What is the common practice to store session attributes? 
I am planning to use ngStorage directive and use sessionstorage and store it by encoding with Base64. Is it a good way to do it?

I am using Java 1.7 and Angular JS for building an application. I have used JHipster to generate the application.

Any Help Appriciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

welcome! Well, depends the situation, localStorage is an excellent option to store attributes, but yes, it has some limitations and you have to remember to delete this. Another options is to use [Cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) of angular project to store attributes on Client Side. I used in some projects and works perfectly for my use case. But if you are using Java, the best way is protect this session attributes using Java [HttpServletSessions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). I Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am using restful  java services on the backend. I cannot really use HTTPServletSessions to store the data. Any idea on sessionStorage instead of localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i resolved by find the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/922058/5995665
I hope it helps.

Comment: You can link to concrete answer by clicking on the share button below the answer.